# Prove that $3x^3- 7y^3+21 z^3=2$ has no integer solutions.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have this math problem I'm kind of stuck on.

> Prove that $3x^3- 7y^3+21 z^3=2$ has no integer solutions.

The reason I am stuck on this problem is because I am supposed to be using modular arithmetic to prove it. I'm not really sure where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use mod $7$ to find that $3x^3\equiv 2\pmod{7}$. But by [Fermat's Little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $x^6\equiv \{0,1\}\pmod{7}$, so $x^3\equiv \{0,\pm 1\}\pmod{7}$, so $3x^3\equiv \{0,\pm 3\}\equiv \{0,3,4\}\not\equiv 2\pmod{7}$.